# static const variable from a another static const variable gives compile error?

Tags: c++, c

Why this compiles:

```
static const short test_value = 0x0100;
static const uint8_t *is_big_endian = ((const uint8_t *) &test_value);
```

but this doesn't:

```
static const short test_value = 0x0100;
static const uint8_t is_big_endian = *((const uint8_t *) &test_value);
```

with the error:

> expression must have a constant value

I made up some false sense about it and tried the following:

```
static uint8_t is_big_endian = *((const uint8_t *) &test_value);
```

Which also didn't compile and produced the same error!
I also have tried to play with the location of the `const` but nothing worked.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Edit:
It seems to work in C++ but not C. So now my questions are:

1. Why it isn't compiling in C?
2. What C++ does different that enables it?

---

Comment: In C, the contents of a `const`-qualified object are not *constant*; they're `/* read-only */`.

Comment: It should compile and it does on MSVC and gcc, are you sure you've recompiled your project?

Comment: Which language are you talking about? C or C++? They are different languages and also have different view upon what is considered suitable for initializing static objects or not.

Comment: Is this C or C++? It compiles (VS-2019) as C++ but not as C ... they are different languages with different rules.

Comment: When C compiler complains about needing a constant value it means a value that is also already known at compile time. Dereferencing a pointer does not qualify for that.

Comment: I am 100% sure I recompiled it and it's not compiling.
It is in a .c file but it's a part of a C++ project (in VS2019 both are compiled by the same compiler - cl.exe).

Comment: @Gerhardh but I can use the address as a pointer to a constant location (as in the compiled code of the question). If the compiler can know the address in advance and knows it referencing a constant value, it can knew in advance what byte it will reference.

Comment: The cl.exe program runs as *either* a C compiler *or* as a C++ compiler, depending on what you tell it to do. Look at your "Advanced" settings for the file containing the code you've posted and set it to compile as C++ (the default for a ".c" file is to compile as C).

Comment: No, the compiler does not know anything of that. As pmg already mentioned, `const` only means "read-only". Such a pointer could also point to some hardware register of a clock or similar which clearly changes during runtime..

Comment: So In C it doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't knew the pointer points to an actual constant and not just a read-only.
So why it compiles in C++?

Comment: @AdiPeled "_So why it compiles in C++?_" C++, and C are different languages. Different languages can handle similar constructs differently.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Not all C constants are required to have values known at compile time. So may be resolved during linking or program loading.

Comment: @Gerhardh: The compiler may assume a `const Type *` points to ordinary memory, not a register for a clock or something else that may change. It is only required to assume the pointed-to-memory may change if the pointer is qualified with `volatile`.

Comment: As noted, you need to edit the question and clarify if this is C or C++, since the answers will be quite different. Please edit the question and remove one of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not require compilers to figure out the bytes that make up an object while evaluating expressions for initializers. So, while `*((const uint8_t *) &test_value)` might have a logically determined value that you can figure out from knowledge of `test_value`, the compiler is not required to figure it out.

C 2018 6.8 7 says a constant expression used in an initializer may be an arithmetic constant expression, a null pointer constant, an address constant, or an address constant plus or minus an integer constant expression. The expression `*((const uint8_t *) &test_value)` is not any of the latter three forms, since they are pointers of various kinds. Let’s consider the first form, an arithmetic constant expression.

C 2018 6.8 8 defines *arithmetic constant expression*:

> An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

So `*((const uint8_t *) &test_value)` is not an arithmetic constant expression because it contains a cast of a pointer, not an arithmetic type, and that cast is not part of an operand to `sizeof` or `_Alignof`. It also contains `test_value` as an operand, and that is not one of the list permissible kinds of operand. It also contains `&test_value` as an operand, and that is also not one of the permissible kinds.